# Selecting multiple items from the Custom list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, list

This is the code to get the list of divisions and add a custom "Select all" at the top

---

```
IList<Division> divisionList = divisionService.GetAllDivisions();
divisionList.Insert(0, new Division() { Code = "ALL", CodeName = "Select all" });
```

---

Then filter it based on the Code, I get 1 item in newList

---

```
var newList = divisionList.Where(x => x.Code == "01" ).ToList();
```

---

Question is how to select multiple items ans store it in newList, including "Select All"
Getting an empty list with this statement,

---

```
var newList = divisionList.Where(x => x.Code == "01" && x.Code == "02" ).ToList();
```

---

Comment: What is the actual question or problem? This code should already do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a logical or not a logical and... like this:

```
var newList = divisionList.Where(x => x.Code == "01" || 
                                      x.Code == "02" || 
                                      x.Code == "All" ).ToList();
```